Short description of "trusted user" privilege lacks an Oxford comma, violating SE's own style guidelines
Company guidance says to "Use the oxford [sic] comma in sentences." However, the short description of the "trusted user" privilege says "Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges" - that is, it lacks an Oxford comma. I acknowledge that this isn't a sentence. Yet, since the other three-item lists among the privilege descriptions (e.g. "participate in meta"'s "Discuss the site itself: bugs, feedback, and governance") use a comma after the second list item, could the extra comma be added to "trusted user"?

I don't think this style guide is very good. The "commas" section would be much improved by a semicolon (so it's one sentence per instruction), but semicolons are outright forbidden. Also, the style guide itself does not use Oxford commas consistently. The first paragraph on "active tense" [sic: they were thinking of "active voice"] is actually about "imperative mood"…

In reality, does it really, truely matter? This one case.

@security_paranoid I've gotten an Oxford comma added to NLN flags, so yes, I think grammar bug reports are valid

@security_paranoid great buildings are built from very small bricks. Of course one brick does not matter, it can stay broken. But, does it mean people should leave it  broken on purpose? I don't think so.

@ShadowWizard are great buildings built because the builders obsessed over one dysfunctional brick? I think not. I know my comment(s) sound somewhat rude, but the question is whether or not such issues demand the attention they get. But you are clearly more knowledgeable/experienced than me, so I’ll take your word that this small brick does matter.
